# can't fill background color of this polygon on Android Google map

Tags: android, google-maps

Polygon is showing well on google map.

But when I try to paint the background using  fillColor property, it doesn't work.

Other polygons have no problem at all, so it is judged that there is a problem with these coordinates, but I am not sure what the problem is.
It even works well on iOS and doesn't work well on Android.
The coordinate array of polygon that I'm trying to draw is as below.
How can i solve this problem?

[[139.6961904465721,35.67366716851985],[139.69825038309554,35.67066895010819],[139.69267138834456,35.66923952726723],[139.69262847300033,35.6729873497998],[139.6961904465721,35.67366716851985]]